# to remove xml root attribute

Tags: java, regex, xml, string

i want to remove attribute of parent tag via regex,   string handling please help
`<root xmlns="http://schemas.abc.com/ess/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" abcId="sip:+14184400781@ims.mnc510.mcc302.3gppnetwork.org"><tag1>a</tag1><tag2>b</tag2><tag3>c</tag3></root>`

i want output to be like this
`<root><tag1>a</tag1><tag2>b</tag2><tag3>c</tag3></root>`

Comment: Why regex? It is most likely the wrong tool for this.

Comment: First, questions should provide a [mcve] including what you have tried. Never parse HTML/XML with regex: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Why does that even matter?  Surely you can parse the XML document as it is.  Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-reg.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you provide some examples of why it is hard to parse XML and HTML with a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-reg)

Answer (score 0):

> *"... i want to remove attribute of parent tag via regex, string handling ..."*

You can use the following pattern.

```
(?s)(?<=<root)\s.+?(?<!]])(?=>)
```

- `(?s)` will toggle-on *single-line* mode
- `(?<=<root)\s` will assert the match starts with the text, *"<root"*
- `.+?(?<!]])(?=>)` will match everything up to a *>*, which is not a *]]>*

Here is an example, where *s* is your provided text.

```java
s = s.replaceAll("(?s)(?<=<root)\\s.+?(?<!]])(?=>)", "");
```

Output

```
<root><tag1>a</tag1><tag2>b</tag2><tag3>c</tag3></root>
```

Comment: Like all attempts to modify XML using regular expressions, this code is wrong. For example it will fail if the attributes are separated by tabs rather than spaces. Regexes are simply the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: @MichaelKay, why would this fail on a _tab_ character?

Comment: Actually it will fail on a newline but not on a tab (because of single-line mode). It will also fail, I think, if the root element has no attributes.

Comment: @MichaelKay, it shouldn't, unless I am over-looking something.  _Single-line_ mode is when the `.` syntax will additionally match `\r` and `\n`.  And, regarding it failing when there are no attributes, the _pattern_ is meant for a _substitution_ routine, not just a _find_.